# Using [FromQuery] with a complex object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having an issue with my parameter not binding when I send a request to my API endpoint when passing a query string, the parameter binds if I flatten Submission but this isn't the solution I want. I can't provide the client-side code that sends the request as a third party control handles the request.

I've supplied an example of the query string sent with the request that can be seen in developer tools, however, Person and Property come back as null. Does anyone have any suggestions, specifically server-side changes that I can do to bind this complex object? thanks.

```
public class Submission {
    public Person Person {get; set; }
    public Property Property { get; set; }
}

public class Person {
   public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Property {
   public string Address { get; set; }
}

Query string parameters

'Person[Age]': 18
'Property[Address]': test

 [HttpGet("action")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Submit([FromQuery] Submission model)
 {

 }
```

Comment: Try `Person.Age` in the querystring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your action :

```
[HttpGet("Submit")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Submit([FromQuery] Submission model)
{

}
```

Try this for your Submission model

```
public class Submission {
    public int Age {
        set { 
           if (Person == null) Person = new Person();
           Person.Age = value;
        }
    }
    public string Address {
        set { 
           if (Person == null) Person = new Person();
           Person.Address = value;
        }
    }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public Property Property { get; set; }
}
```

or you can create

```cs
public class SubmissionModel : Submission
{
    public int Age {
        set { 
            if (Person == null) Person = new Person();
            Person.Age = value;
        } 
    }
}
```

in this case you action will be

```
[HttpGet("Submit")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Submit([FromQuery] SubmissionModel subModel)
{
    var model = subModel as Submission;
    // other code here
}
```

In this case you have to call this URL:

`https://localhost:.../.../submit?Age=18&Address=myaddress`

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, flattening the object does work, however, my example is a simplified version and I'd prefer to not flatten my multinested class.Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 5):

In this case the URL you want to call is:

```
https://localhost:.../.../action?Person.Age=18&Property.Address=test
```