# ASP.NET Core minimal API's and parameter binding -> QueryString into a POCO (like how a Body goes into a POCO)?

Tags: c#, minimal-apis, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm trying to get my simple ASP.NET Core 7 minimal API to automatically bind the QueryString parameters into a single POCO.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0

For example:

```
https://localhost:5000/some/endpoint?a=1&b=hello&c=true

public record Query(int? A, string? B, bool? C); // Notice how all are optional!

public static async Task<Ok<List<Result>>> HandleAsync(
    Query query,
    MyDbContext myDbContext,
    HttpContext context,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
)
{ .. }
```

If I do that, the framework is thinking/expecting the `Query` item to be `[FromBody]`. I've also tried this

```
[FromQuery] Query query,
```

but that also didn't work. (Unless I did something wrong).

Of course, this would work:

```
public static async Task<Ok<List<Result>>> HandleAsync(
    int? a,
    string? b,
    bool? c,
    MyDbContext myDbContext,
    HttpContext context,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
)
```

but I don't want/like that. What can I try next?

Comment: What if you change the record into a class? Also try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64794376/using-fromquery-with-a-complex-object

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741284/asp-net-core-fromquery-usage-and-url-format

Answer (score 2):

Use [`AsParametersAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#parameter-binding-for-argument-lists-with-asparameters):

> `AsParametersAttribute` enables simple parameter binding to types and not complex or recursive model binding.

```
public static async Task<Ok<List<Result>>> HandleAsync(
    [AsParameters] Query query,
    MyDbContext myDbContext,
    HttpContext context,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
)
{
    ... 
}
```

Comment: and this should work when `Query` is a `record` ? also, `Query` is a "flat" `record` .. meaning all simple Types. no custom/complex classes as the properties.

Comment: @Pure.Krome I have tested it with record (from your question).

Answer (score 0):

If you change record to class it should work.

```cs
public class Query
{
    public int? A { get; set; }
    public string? B { get; set; }
    public bool? C { get; set; }
}
```